# I think that my cordova/phonegap app dont execute JS

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap, html-framework-7

As I sad in title i have problem with cordova/phonegap. First of all my F7 icons dont show up and all F7 dont execute on my friends tablet but on my phone everything works properly. First image is 4.3 android and second image is 4.4.4 android.
[image: **My friend tablet:**]

[image: **My phone:**e]

**Logs**

```
E/Web Console(20366): Uncaught Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12 at file:///android_asset/www/js/my-app.js:35
```

Comment: have u checked the ios version?

Comment: @tibetty I am using android devices and I edited my question for andoid version.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? You can debug Android WebViews with Chrome via `chrome://inspect`

Comment: Get your friends device connected via USB on a PC with ADB drivers for your friends phone installed then take a look at this in chrome://inspect/#devices

Comment: @MStoner Ok I will try to guide my friend but it will take some time

Comment: You can also try running a matching 4.3 emulator on your development machine and see if you can replicate the issue.

Comment: @DarthJDG Can you recommend some?

Comment: Use the standard AVD included with the Android SDK. Just download the Android 4.3 images via the Android SDK manager and set up your virtual devices.

Comment: I have seen errors on same Android version on one device, then not on another. This happened with LET vs. VAR was used and USE STRICT was not included. I agree with DarthJDG need to see the console for errors.

Comment: I used adb logcat to get errors but problem is that i dont know what error i need to search using grep(FINDSTR in windows).

Comment: @DarthJDG I edited my post for logs